# Adjusting Margin and Spacing for Radio Button Choices

Tags: html, css

I possess the code for a radio button with everything functioning as intended

```css
div > label {
    margin-right: 80px !important;
    box-shadow: .3rem .3rem .6rem #c8d0e7, 
-.2rem -.2rem .5rem #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 1.4rem;
    height: 1.4rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

div > label::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.6rem;
    height: 0.6rem;
    background: #9baacf;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

div > label:has(input:checked)::after{
  background: #6c7ae0;
}
div > label > input{
  display: none;
}

div > label:hover::after{
  background: #6c7ae0;
}

div > label > span {
    color: #9baacf;
    margin-left: 130px !important;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 82px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="all">
        <span>All</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="upcoming">
        <span>Upcoming</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="expired">
        <span>Expired</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm unable to pinpoint where I might have overlooked it, but there seems to be a discrepancy in the spacing or margin between the text and the circular button for all three choices. My objective is to achieve a consistent margin of 10 pixels before the  element and the circular button.

Comment: `Run code snippet` > `Ctrl+Shift+I` (inspect) > click on the little arrow on the top left and select your element with it: you have a `margin-left: 130px !important;` value on `div > label > span `

Comment: If I remove that margin, everything becomes stacked on top of each other

Comment: I understand you want your input dependant on the `:checked` property but this value can be inherited, you should nest your visible radial button and use `input:checked + .myRadioButton` to select the next element and style it, otherwise you are giving your reference element `label` the width of your button, hence the wrong margins

Comment: I'm unable to include any HTML code since I'm working with a predefined component. Thus, I only have access to the input and span elements within it.

Comment: If you want a visually consistent spacing between choices with text of different lengths, you won't be able to set a width on any of the elements containing the text. There's currently a width set for the <label> elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the CSS code but in the structure itself and how CSS interacts with it.

For readability purposes I hade to add to `div` a `.radialHolder` class.
Some errors found, `checked` was causing the element to be constantly selected, and a radio button without a `name` property works as independant.

Over-all, here's your code with that `input:checked + .myRadioButton` as specified in the comments, this structure will give you more flexibility in future edits

```css
.radialHolder > label > .myRadialButton {
    /*margin-right: 80px !important;*/
    box-shadow: .3rem .3rem .6rem #c8d0e7, 
-.2rem -.2rem .5rem #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 1.4rem;
    height: 1.4rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.radialHolder > label > .myRadialButton::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.6rem;
    height: 0.6rem;
    left: 0.4rem; /* parent width/2 - element width/2 */
    top: 0.4rem; /* parent width/2 - element width/2 */
    background: #9baacf;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.radialHolder > label > input:checked + .myRadialButton::after{
  background: #6c7ae0;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
.radialHolder label input{
  display: none;
}

.radialHolder > label:hover > .myRadialButton::after{
  background: #6c7ae0;
}

.radialHolder > label > span {
    color: #9baacf;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.radialHolder {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    /*width: fit-content;*/
    height: 82px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="radialHolder">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="all" name="mychoices">
        <div class="myRadialButton"></div>
        <span>All</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="upcoming" name="mychoices">
        <div class="myRadialButton"></div>
        <span>Upcoming</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="expired" name="mychoices">
        <div class="myRadialButton"></div>
        <span>Expired</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT** Based on the comment, this is a solution involving only input+span. Since this gives a solution to a very specific problem I will still leave the preferred method here and give **this [codepen as solution](https://codepen.io/savageGoat/pen/Bavzmxz)**

Comment: I'm unable to include any HTML code since I'm working with a predefined component. Thus, I only have access to the input and span elements within it.

Comment: Sorry I just saw your comment, let me do a hacky solution. Not the best but it would work

Comment: @bxxb here's your solution based only on the `:before` and `:after` selectors. Basically, `span:before` creates the background of the button and `span:after` the interaction indicator and absolute positionning based on the padding does the trick. A very hacky way to do it, yet, works